# How to insert missing rows in a data frame based on another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames:

```
x <- structure(list(Cluster1 = c(53L, NA, NA), Cluster10 = c(48L, 
46L, NA), Cluster11 = c(2L, NA, NA)), row.names = c("Cluster1", 
"Cluster10", "Cluster11"), class = "data.frame")

y <- tructure(list(Cluster1 = c(53L, NA), Cluster10 = c(46L, NA), 
    Cluster11 = c(2L, NA)), row.names = c("Cluster1", "Cluster11"
), class = "data.frame")
```

It looks like this:

```
> x
          Cluster1 Cluster10 Cluster11
Cluster1        53        48         2
Cluster10       NA        46        NA
Cluster11       NA        NA        NA

> y
          Cluster1 Cluster10 Cluster11
Cluster1        53        46         2
Cluster11       NA        NA        NA
```

Now, `y` miss a row in `x` that is `Cluster10`. How can I insert that missing row and fill it with value NAs. 
The final desired output for `y` is:

```
          Cluster1 Cluster10 Cluster11
Cluster1        53        48         2
Cluster10       NA        NA        NA
Cluster11       NA        NA        NA
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an option:

```
y[setdiff(row.names(x), row.names(y)),] <- NA

          Cluster1 Cluster10 Cluster11
Cluster1        53        46         2
Cluster11       NA        NA        NA
Cluster10       NA        NA        NA
```